# window.location does not work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, safari, location

I have below script to open an email client and redirect the page to avoid blank, however the script is works fine in `Firefox` and `IE`, but `Chrome` and `Safari` does not open an email client but just redirect to the url, is that any work around to solve the issue?

```
if(!empty($emails)){
    echo '<script>
    window.location = "mailto:abc@site.com?cc=xyz@site.com&bcc='.$emails.'&subject=Hello:";
    window.location = "http://www.site.com/current_page.php";
    </script>';
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
window.location.href
```

instead of

```
window.location
```

even better to use

The following works for me in current versions of IE, FireFox, Chrome, and Safari for Windows (fiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/MgX9U/)

```
window.location.replace("mailto:?subject=hi&body=content");
```

EDIT:
us setTimeout function before the second call, and make a delay for the second call.

Comment: actually i had try `location.href` and `location.assign`, but no luck.

Comment: i have given you the link that i tried myself on chrome as well. Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: my script is works on all browsers when I put only `window.location=mailto:xxx` without second `window.location` for redirect purpose.

Comment: I solved it by using setTimeout function to delay the second one a bit and it works fine.